# How to send email using basic php?

Tags: php

enquiry.php

```
     <form  id="style_contact" method="POST" name="contactForm" action="sendmail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" align="left">
                          <tr>
                            <td>Name<span style="color:#96070d; padding:5px;">*</span></td>
                            <td><input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="" class="feiald" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Telephone<span style="color:#96070d; padding:5px;">*</span></td>
                            <td><input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="" class="feiald" value="" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Mobile No<span style="color:#96070d; padding:5px;">*</span></td>
                            <td><input name="mobile" type="text" placeholder="" class="feiald" value="" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Email<span style="color:#96070d; padding:5px;">*</span></td>
                            <td><input name="email" type="text" placeholder="" class="feiald" value="" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Subject<span style="color:#96070d; padding:5px;">*</span></td>
                            <td><input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="" class="feiald" value="" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Message<span style="color:#96070d; padding:5px;">*</span></td>
                            <td><textarea name="message" cols="36" rows="3" class="feiald" placeholder=""></textarea></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                             <td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
        </form>
```

sendmail.php

```
               <?php


    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $telephone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'cd4xltech@gmail.com';

    $message = 'Name : '.$name.'Telephone : '.$telephone.'Mobile No : '.$mobile.'Email : '.$email.'Message : '.$msg;

    mail($to,$subject,$message);


    header('location: enquiry.php?msg="Your message has been sent successfully!!"');
```

?>

I have written the code for sending email to an email-id in basic php. And I have uploaded onto the server. But it is not working. Can anyone tell what is the mistake in this code ? The message "Your message has been sent successfully" is being displayed. But mail is not in the inbox.

Comment: The basic PHP `mail` function is notorious for triggering junk filters, especially in Google. Have you checked your junk box?

Comment: Have you configured a mail server like Exim?

Comment: there are no mails in junk box.

Comment: You should try a third party mailer, like PHPmailer or the likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one...very simple,  it will help u for sure

```html
     <?php 
   $to = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
   $subject = "This is Test Mail";
   $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
   $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";
   $header = "From:yyyyyy@gmail.com\r\n";
   $header .= "Cc:xxx@gmail.com \r\n";
   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you ask for simple emails via Php. Then you can use Php mail() method.  Then you need to avoid email from going to spam

Comment: junk means ? If you mean it as trash..there are no mails in the trash. How to prevent it going to junk ?

Comment: no the mail send using the abov code is not in the spam.

Comment: mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg); use this instead :) If this line of code is executed on server side. For sure the email will receive email.  Either in Inbox or in spam.. bt surely it will

Comment: actually the above code was working in another webserver..but when I uploaded the same code onto another server, the message "your message has been sent successfully" is showing but the mail is not there in the inbox or spam. Can anyone tell what is the issue and a solution ?